# JsonResult not return to ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Index(parameters)
    {
       return Json(new { Status = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is my AJax call that successfully run the MVC method.

```
    $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Home/Index",
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                debugger
                if (result == "error") {
                    swal({ text: "No procesado", type: "warning" });
                }
                else {
                    swal({ text: "Correcto", type: "success" });
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
            });
```

The value is not returning to Ajax method, the result stays in the browser, maybe some configuration is necessary in visual studio?

[The return in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV0E2.jpg)

Comment: You're POSTing to that action, so you'll need to mark that action using `[HttpPost]` otherwise it defaults to GET only.

Comment: What do you mean by "not returning"? What does your screenshot show? What does your console show?

Comment: sorry, I edited it

Comment: CodeCaster in the image is the return

Comment: You are sending 'POST' request with ajax and your function marked as [HttpPost] but return Json as JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet. Change type: 'POST' to type:'GET' and mark your function [HttpGet] instead of [HttpPost]

Comment: you should consider using postman to debug this https://www.postman.com/